# Start Gif on Mouseover and then Pause Gif at it's end, and have info pop up after?

Tags: javascript, image, gif, preload

I have a cell phone img, it's broke then gets fixed then the screen pulls up a notepad(on the cell phone) I don't quite get how to make the mouseover turn the screen fixed then open the notepad on it with the "cart" information, how would this work?

Comment: You have to put a little more effort in your question, I'm afraid. I don't think that anyone out there gets what you are asking :)

Comment: Okay here is the gif [link](http://sellyourbrokentech.com/169299.gif) how do I have that not loop, I want it to only start on mouseover and while leaving your mouse on it I want it to pause at the blank part, so I can add text inside it.. as if it were a website shopping cart showing your goods.

Comment: I would recommend to use 3 different images instead of a gif. You really don't do it like that. A gif is not supposed to be used as an UI element.

Comment: @OddDev I'm down to use all three of the images I used to make the gif.. I just don't know how to code it to work for the mouseover I know how to position text over it .. once done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your html looks like this:

```
<img id="img1" src="image1.jpg" />
```

It shows the phone.

Your JS looks like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
    //replace the imagesource with the second image
}, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Do I make a .js for that?

Comment: I'm just confused lol idk how this works and "replace the imagesource" where is the imagesource in that js code?

Comment: In the img tag (the attribute is called 'src'). 
Maybe you should start with a basic html tutorial rather than doing mouseover stuff.

Comment: fthat I got the code up just how do I link the second image so it changes to that?

Comment: img.setAttribute("src", "image2.jp");
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: [link](http://sellyourbrokentech.com/) it's in the middle of that page lol var img = document.getElementById("img1");
img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {    
img.setAttribute("src", "image3.png"); //replace the imagesource with the second image
}, false); named this fiddle.js and nothing seems to change?